# structure sheaf of a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have the following problem:

Let $X$ be a scheme and $x$ a closed point on it.
If $F$ is a sheaf on X with nontrivial stalk $F_x$ at $x$, then one has a canonical surjective morphism $F\rightarrow G$, where $G$ is the structure sheaf of the point $x$.
I dont understand how to describe $G$ and where this morphism comes from and why it should be surjective.
Perhaps one can explain that in detail for me.

Thank you very much

Comment: Dear Descartes, What makes you think such a canonical map exists? (It doesn't.)  Also, what do you mean by the structure sheaf of $x$?  Are you thinking of $x$ as the underlying topological space of Spec $\kappa(x)$?  Regards,

Comment: well, I mean x as a closed subscheme

Comment: Dear Descartes, Yes, but which scheme structure?  The reduced one?  Regards,

Comment: @Descartes: If this coming from a textbook or some lecture notes, can you give a citation? It may be more helpful to see it in context. If I had to guess, I would say that $G$ is the direct image sheaf under the obvious morphism $\{ x \} \hookrightarrow X$. (This is also known as the skyscraper sheaf.)

Comment: well, the proof where it occurs is rather involved; but it comes down to the following: you have a sheaf F, take a closed point in its support and then you have this morphism from F to k(x); I have called G what the author calls k(x); but he doesn't say what he means with that

Comment: Dear Descartes, $k(x)$ (what I called $\kappa(x)$ above) means the residue field at $x$, i.e. the residue field of the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,x}$.  Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map exists (under some hypotheses --- e.g. $\mathcal F$ is a coherent sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules), but is not canonical.

We can form the stalk $\mathcal F_x$, which is a module over $\mathcal O_{X,x}$.  We can then form the fibre $\mathcal F_x /\mathfrak m_x \mathcal F_x$, which is
a vector space over $\kappa(x)$.  If the original sheaf $\mathcal F$ was coherent,
and $x$ is in its support, then the fibre will be non-zero.  Any non-zero vector space over $\kappa(x)$ admits a surjective map to $\kappa(x)$.  (If a vector space $V$ is non-zero then the same is true of its dual.)

Choosing such a non-zero map $\mathcal F_x/\mathfrak m_x \mathcal  F_x \to
\kappa(x)$,
we obtain the map $\mathcal F \to \mathcal G$ that you are asking about.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I wanted. Sorry for the error with "canonical", but in the text it looked as if it was.